# How future-proof is it to force a structure alignment with `__attribute__((packed,aligned(N)))`?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I have a struct, whose relevant part is:

```c
typedef struct {
    uint64_t *num;
    ...
} name;
```

It would naturally have alignment 8 in most architectures, but for reasons (legacy reasons), I need it to have alignment 4, as I can guarantee the latter alignment, but not the former.

A solution I've found is adding `__attribute__((packed,aligned(4)))` to the declaration.
I've tested it at godbolt.com and it indeed works and produces the correct number of loads on every architecture they have.

[GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) make no special mention for this combination and clang docs don't mention these attributes at all.

My question is, how portable (between unix-like environments) and future-proof would this be?
Could next year's GCC/clang break the whole thing?

Should I prefer `#pragma pack(4)` to it, which looks pretty much equivalent?

Comment: I don't see it as very portable or future-proof. Considering that the structure contains pointers, you most likely will not be saving it to files in binary form, or sending it through a network connection? Can you perhaps modify the structure? Add "manual padding" using member variables to make sure that this member is on a 64-bit (8-byte) boundary? Perhaps by reordering the existing members?

Comment: "legacy reasons" are bad reasons - this is *compiled code* after all. There is nothing future-proof about packing - even this day it is mostly a horrible kludge.

Comment: I understand they're bad reasons, but exactly because it's compiled, I'd prefer not rehauling the whole memory storage if the compiler can cope with it.

Comment: For the alignment part you should use standard `_Alignas`. This can't be put on the type, but on the 1st member of the `struct`, e.g. Packed is not standard, but the `#pragma` version is understood by all compilers that I touched.

Comment: *I need it to have alignment 4* For a structure with nothing more than a *pointer* in it?  That is ... strange.

Comment: `_Alignas()` is C11, sadly I'm still at C99. Sure, GCC supports it in 99 mode as well, but we're back at the start.

Comment: @AndrewHenle , that is the **relevant** part, there are other things. I'll edit for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

`__attribute__(packed)` is for gcc, some other compilers like clang may understand it but others like visual studio wont... The C compiler will use whatever is normal for the abi, see: [The Lost Art of C Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)

really the best thing you can do is find an optimal natural packing:

order them from largest to smallest... and you will end up with the smallest struct naturally packed...

or if you only need to use GCC on linux then just use the packed attribute and go on about your merry way, know that it wont work everywhere.

Comment: Portability to MSVC isn't a concern, as I wrote. I had already read the link, but it doesn't help in this case.

Comment: @12345ieee, what is your goal with packed and aligned 4?

Comment: To keep the thing short, this struct is intermixed with another struct of alignment 4 in a big memory area. On 32bit arches, everything was fine, as pointers needed alignment 4, and now I can't overhaul the whole thing, especially because unaligned access is free in x86_64.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the whole thing could be broken in any future release. Compilers only need to implement the C standard, and reserve the right to withdraw such niceties as you are relying upon, particularly if their implementation becomes unfeasible in future architectures.

It might be rather simplistic, but your best bet is to hit the legacy issues head on. To me this comes into the "always fix bugs before writing new code" genre.

Comment: I find this view to be a bit extreme. To say one, the linux kernel relies on a ton of gnu extensions (`packed` is one of those), I find it difficult to think it will stop being supported abruptly by gcc, but I still wanted to ask if someone knew better.

Comment: Eh, AVX registers are 512 bits wide, that doesn't mean x86_64 can't address my bytes one by one. Future architectures might not support long unaligned loads, but what I'm asking the compiler is to find a clever way to load an unaligned variable, even byte by byte if necessary, which will always be possible. I understand though that the compiler isn't forced to do all this work for me and might stop at any release, as you said.